# How can I "bypass" Tailwind's JIT. I'm building a button component out of variables and styles doesn't render

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm using Laravel 8, and just build a `<x-button>` component. Since I want to use it for several colors and font sizes, I wrote it like this:

```
@props(['color' => 'default', 'size' => 'normal'])

@php
$_color = $color == 'default'
  ? "bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-800"
  : "bg-$color-500 hover:bg-$color-800";

$_color .= in_array($color, ['blue', 'gray', 'red', 'green', 'orange', 'sky'])
  ? " text-white"
  : " text-black";
$_color .= in_array($color, ['amber'])
  ? " hover:text-white"
  : "";

$_size = "text-$size";
@endphp

<button {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => "$_color $_size px-2 py-1 font-bold uppercase rounded-lg shadow spacing-nowrap"]) }}>
  {{ $slot }}
</button>
```

So idea here is I can call `<x-button color="red" size="2xl">` or `<x-button color="cyan" size="xs">` and will apply color, hover state and text color for contrast.

This code works, only problem is that since I'm not using the classes on "static" elements (let me call them that way) the corresponding CSS isn't generated, for example, if I call `<x-button color="green">...</x-button>` will produce:

```
<button class="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-800 text-white text-normal px-2 py-1 font-bold uppercase rounded-lg shadow spacing-nowrap" />...</button>
```

The style for `bg-green-500` doesn't exist, so it produces a transparent button. This is related to the JIT behaivour in Tailwind, if I use a color I'd used before, it renders the CSS correctly.

So, is there a way to bypass/disable JIT, just for colors and text sizes?

---

I know solution to this would be chaging my code to something like:

```
switch($color) {
  case 'green':
  case 'success':
    $_color = "bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-800 text-white";
    break;
  // ...
}
```

I know this works, this is how I used to made my components, but I really wanted to do something shorter and more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [safelist](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) classes

It is possible to pass class as simple string but it leads to same `switch-case` repetitive problem. So it better to use regular expression for two dynamic classes (`bg-$color-500 hover:bg-$color-800`)

If you don't care much about optimization you may safelist every possible config color with `500` and `800` keys and `hover` variant like this

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  safelist: [
    {
        pattern: /bg-.+-(500|800)/,
        variants: ['hover'],
    },
  ],
}
```

However it will generate a lot of extra classes. So I would suggest to separate them

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  safelist: [
    {
        // `$`-sign at the end required if you do NOT wish to generate
        // every `opacity-class` like `bg-red-500/5`, `bg-red-500/10` etc
        // This way only `bg-red-500` and `bg-green-500` will be safelisted
        pattern: /bg-(red|green)-500$/,
    },
    {
        pattern: /bg-(red|green)-800$/,
        variants: ['hover'],
    },
  ],
}
```

It is still not ideal as you have to add same colors (`(red|green|sky|orange|...)`) twice. So you may change it to something like this

```js
// Add colors here
const colors = ['blue', 'gray', 'red', 'green', 'orange', 'sky', 'amber']

const safelist = colors.map(color => `bg-${color}-500 hover:bg-${color}-800`)

module.exports = {
  safelist,
}
```

Check [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/RpQqXgs8ry?file=config) - despite I have empty HTML with no classes, there are actually some classes were generated in CSS (click Generated CSS at the bottom, Utilities tab)

Comment: Very nice, very clever... I'm learning some clever ways to use JS. I'll try that!